# Discord.js setStatus() and setPresence() not working

Tags: javascript, discord.js

The bot starts and works perfectly, but these lines don't execute, nor do I get an error on boot:

```js
//status set
client.on('ready', ready => {
    client.user.setStatus('dnd')
    client.user.setPresence({
        game: {
            name: 'Use "-help"',
            type: "Playing",
            url: "https://discordapp.com/"
        }
    })
});
```

I have tried changing the handler to do this when a certain command (-status) is used, but the handler kicks in, and the code does nothing...

Comment: Can you add in a log line at the op of the event to see if it's actually triggering or not?

Answer (score 1):

Try using [setActivity](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=setActivity)

```
client.user.setActivity('Use "-help"', { type: 'PLAYING', url: 'https://discordapp.com/' });
```

Comment: Sorry for not anwering earlier!! I dont know what i did and didnt work, but i changed some things up and its fixed now, thank you anyways for your help!

Comment: It's great that you fixed it! You should probably post your answer so that other people in the future can learn from what you did